# Reading line by line the contents of an 80GB .gz file without uncompressing it

Tags: python, c, compression, tar

I have an 80GB .gz file(http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/googlebooks-eng-all-3gram-20120701-th.gz), which contains one tab delimited file that is much larger. Is there a way in which I can reproduce line by line the contents of that file without loading 80GB into memory, or uncompressing the file?
There are specific lines in that file that I need (about 10000) but I don't have 80GB of RAM or more than 1TB storage space to uncompress it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `zcat` to stream the uncompressed contents into `grep` or whatever filter you want, without incurring space overhead.  E.g.

```
zcat bigfile.gz | grep PATTERN_I_NEED > much_smaller_sample
```

Also, if it's just grep you're streaming to, you can use `zgrep` e.g.

```
zgrep PATTERN_I_NEED bigfile.gz > much_smaller_sample
```

but `zgrep` doesn't support 100% of the features of `grep` on some systems.

Comment: Instead of grep I wrote my own little python script, but it works perfectly with zcat. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Decompression takes place in *chunks*, and you don't need to hold all of the decompressed data in memory to get to a specific line.

You can combine the [`gzip` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html) with the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and process the file row by row:

```
import gzip
import csv

with gzip.open('googlebooks-eng-all-3gram-20120701-th.gz', 'rb') as fobj:
    reader = csv.reader(fobj, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

Now you can scan for the rows you want; as long as you don't try to store all rows in a list object but instead process them individually, you won't be using much memory at all.

Quick demo:

```
>>> import gzip
>>> import csv
>>> fobj = gzip.open('/tmp/googlebooks-eng-all-3gram-20120701-th.gz', 'rb')
>>> reader = csv.reader(fobj, delimiter='\t')
>>> print next(reader)
["T'Hooft , _NOUN_", '1937', '1', '1']
```

I used the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) here to get just one row at a time from the reader but the principles are the same as using the reader in a loop.

The above uses very little memory; no more than a few kilobytes in file buffers and the current chunk to decompress, plus the Python strings in the `row` list.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you need to decompress from the beginning. However, you don't need to read it all into memory at once. As far as I recall, the python implementations read into memory, but you could run gzip as an external tool and use its stdout as the source of your csv reader. This has the nice benefit of parallelizing the decompression in a separate processor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use python take a look at [gzip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html). The premise is the same as iterating through a regular text file, i.e.

```
import gzip
gz = gzip.GzipFile('/path/file.gz')
for i in gz:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the zlib module https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/zlib.html#module-zlib

Answer (score -1):

this is what I've used in the past

```
  BUFF_SIZE = 120000
  with open(src, 'rb') as src, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
     # prevent loading too much data to memory
     for n,x in enumerate(iter(lambda: src.read(BUFF_SIZE),"")):
        fdst.write(x)
```

obviously this copies the contents of one file to another file, seems to be a bit faster than similar implementations. You can change buff size to whatever size you want to load to memory